# How can I change the default properties of a printer on Windows?

Tags: windows, printer

I have a laser printer that is capable of both color and duplex output and am printing to it from Windows XP.  Every time something is printed the printer properties default to color, single side output.  Is there a way to change the defaults to mono and duplex output so they don't have to be manually set for every print job?

I've looked throughout the "xxxx Printer Properties" pages an have not found a way to save the changes or set them as the new defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Windows XP**

> - Click Start
> - Select Printers and Faxes.
> - Right click on the printer you want to change and select Properties.
> - Click on the Printer preferences… button
> - preferences window for that printer will open up.
> - Make any changes you want to the print preferences and when finished,
>     click OK.

**For Windows Vista/7**

> - Click Start
> - Select Devices and Printers.
> - Right click on the printer you want to change .
> - Select Printer preferences
> - preferences window for that printer will open up.
> - Make any changes you want to the print preferences and when finished,
>     click OK.

Answer (score 1):

XP? You need to access printer properties in Printers and Faxes, right click on the printer and select properties, a window will open, usually there is a "preferences" button, click that to set your preferences permanently.

W7, go to Devices and Printers, right click on the printer icon and select printing preferences.

.

Answer (score -2):

No this not not a solution, as i have a Canon 5325 FAX SCAN and Print, i have saved my own settings, but when ever i have to print from Pdf of Microsoft office it goes back to default setting for printer, i have tried alot to save my settings as default but no success. can any one help in this matter as this is probloem for me and also a lose of money as well.

Regards

Jawad